# Is there an open source version of s3distcp?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, elastic-map-reduce

I would love to use s3distcp for copying data from S3 buckets to S3 buckets but I have the need to use an external proprietary encryption mechanism to ensure the data is encrypted at rest (keeping the keys to myself so amazon could not decrypt)

I would love to do a git clone and create my own s3distcp (with hooks for external encryption/decryption libraries).

I googled and found a potential here https://github.com/libin/s3distcp
But it's not an Amazon account (apparently) and doesn't look like it's documented/updated.

Answer (score 1):

I built a tool that runs in Node.js to copy data from buckets to buckets.

https://github.com/Homefinder/bucketCloner

It uses the AWS JavaScript SDK and isn't very complicated.  You could easily modify it for your purposes, assuming you still have this need of course.